# Captcha page description box bug; border broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The [/captcha page](https://english.stackexchange.com/captcha)'s Are you human box's right border is acting funky:

[image]

That weird line after Human is supposed to be the right border with the Fleur-de-lis.

I get the issue in the three main browsers; IE9, FF15, Chrome 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put in a fix for this. It's already on dev, will be live after the next production build.

Comment: It's broken now.